# Slim php / Eloquent custom query for hasMany-relation

Tags: php, sql, eloquent, slim

I'm currently working with Slim php-framework and eloquent-database:
https://www.slimframework.com/docs/cookbook/database-eloquent.html

What I want to do is to use a custom SQL-query to set up a hasMany-relation of two models.

Let's say, I have two models "User" and "Entry".

My User.php looks like this

```
class User extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model {
    protected $table = 'users';

    public function entries() {
        return $this->hasMany('foo\bar\Entry');
    }
```

}

To fetch the entries I use the following code which works as expected.

```
$userentries = User::find(1)->entries
```

But, I'd like the entries to be fetched with a custom SQL-query like

```
SELECT e.user_id, e.colB, SUM(e.colC - e.colD) as foobar from entries as e where e.user_id = 1 group by e.colB order by foobar DESC;
```

instead of the default `SELECT * from entries where user_id = 1;` but still keep the Entry-model associated to the User's entries property. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, found a clean solution which is a combination of selectRaw() and eloquent local scopes: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#local-scopes

### prototype:

I played around with the query()-functions to find out, what's possible and came up with this one

```
Entry::query()->selectRaw("SUM(colC - colD) as foobar, colB")->where('user_id', 1)->groupBy('colB')->orderBy('foobar', 'DESC')->get();
```

### to use this in a relation:

the `Entry.php` model looks like this:

```
class Entry extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model {

    public function scopeCustom($query) {
        return $query->selectRaw("SUM(colC - colD) as foobar, colB")->groupBy('colB')->orderBy('foobar', 'DESC')->get();
    }
}
```

### and finally...

I can call it with:

```
User::find(1)->entries()->custom();
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you can do this:

```
$userentries = User::where('some', 'conditon')->with('entries')->get();
```

So you basically just add `with('entries')` to your query.

Comment: Hi, thx for your reply, but I don't think it meets my requirement. To specify what I exactly need, I added the full custom query which I want to perform with eloquent.