# Laravel - Sum a column of a linked table?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a Laravel 5.4 project where I am trying to SUM the column of a linked table, while keeping the eloquentness of laravel, where possible.

---

### Below are the two models I am working with:

Movie Model is connected to the 'movies' table in the database which is filled with movies and movie data:

#### Movie.php

```
class Movie extends Model
{

  public function votes()
  {
    return $this->hasMany(MovieVote::class, 'movie_id');
  }
}
```

---

MovieVote is tied to the 'movies' table with the foreign key 'movies_votes' and contains the vote for that movie. Up vote is 1, Down vote is -1.

#### MovieVote.php

```
class MovieVote extends Model
{
  /**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */

  protected $table = 'movie_votes';

  protected $fillable = ['user_id', 'movie_id', 'vote';

  public function movie()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Movie');
  }
```

---

Everything is pretty straightforward at this point for me, and I can make eloquent queries in tinker such as

```
$movie = App\Movie::find(106)
$movie->votes
```

Which shows me the results. I like the ease of this for sure.

```
=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#688
     all: [
       App\MovieVote {#687
         id: 1,
         user_id: 1,
         movie_id: 106,
         vote: 1,
         created_at: "2017-04-23 03:32:29",
         updated_at: "2017-04-23 03:32:30",
       },
       App\MovieVote {#104
         id: 27,
         user_id: 2,
         movie_id: 106,
         vote: -1,
         created_at: "2017-04-23 04:12:51",
         updated_at: "2017-04-23 04:12:52",
       },
     ],
   }
```

---

#### My problem though...

How can I get all movies where 'vote' sums greater than 1 while keeping everything as an eloquent collection so I can use the parameters such as $movie->title in my view?

I've tried a few "other" ways such as looping and counting votes, adding them to an array, so on and so forth, but I lose all eloquentness, so I have to be missing something...

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem a while ago with Slim PHP Framework and Eloquent. But the solution is much the same.

You can use a scope with a selectRaw.

See my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43139953/1568059